# the below golang code works fine on the system conpiled, however when

Tags: go

The below golang code works fine on the system compiled, however when the compiled binary is moved to another system it fails to connect database. What thing I am doing wrong here in terms of packaging.

```
package main

import (
      "fmt"
      "database/sql"
    _ "github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql"
      "time"
      "os"
)

func main() {

        // Open database connection
    db, err := sql.Open("mysql", "root:passwd@/mysql")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Cannot open connection to schema !!!. \n")
        return
    }
    defer db.Close()

    // Execute the query
    rows, err := db.Exec("update user set password=PASSWORD("NEWPASSWORD") where User='root'")
    _ = rows
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Cannot execute query update !!! \n")
        return
    }
}
```

Comment: Could be some permission issue. What is the error?

Comment: It fails at the second stage, just cannot execute the query, I also tried with some other query on different database and table. same issue.

Comment: And what is the error message?

Comment: @litelite The issue was with support for legacy old password authentication. Had to add `?allowOldPasswords=1` to go-DSN, https://github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql/wiki/old_passwords

Comment: For the record, do NOT discard your error messages.  Log them or return them or panic them or _something_.  Some aren't very helpful, but most at least hint at where you should be looking for the issue.

Answer (score 1):

The issue got resolved. The problem was with support for legacy old password authentication. Had to add append

> db, err := sql.Open("mysql", "root:passwd@/mysql?allowOldPasswords=1")

https://github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql/wiki/old_passwords